# Dagger 2 Null field injection

Tags: java, libgdx, dagger-2, dagger

Hi I've read through other posts but I am not being able to fix it. Basically my issue is that I call .inject and when I want to use the field it's still null.

I have this class:

```
public class Application extends Game implements IApplication {

    @Inject IApplication app;
    @Inject IRouter router;

    public Application(IPlatformCode platformCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        initDagger();
        System.out.println(app); //NULL
        System.out.println(router); //NULL
        router.showPage(Page.MenuPage); //NULL EXCEPTION
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPage(IPage page) {
        setScreen(page);
    }

    protected void initDagger() {
        ApplicationComponent.Initializer.init(this).inject(this);
        RouterComponent.Initializer.init().inject(this);
    }
}
```

I won't show the router because I'm doing the same in app.

My Application component looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component ( modules = {ApplicationModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(IApplication application);
    IApplication getApplication();
    static final class Initializer {
        private Initializer(){}
        public static ApplicationComponent init(IApplication app) {
            return DaggerApplicationComponent
                    .builder()
                    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(app))
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the module:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private IApplication app;

    public ApplicationModule(IApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public IApplication providesApplication(){
        return app;
    }
}
```

As far as I read after calling inject(IApplication) the @Inject IApplication should be injected and have a value but right now it's null.

The generated code looks like this:

```
public final class DaggerApplicationComponent implements ApplicationComponent {
    private Provider<IApplication> providesApplicationProvider;

    private DaggerApplicationComponent(DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder builder) {
        assert builder != null;

        this.initialize(builder);
    }

    public static DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder builder() {
        return new DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder();
    }

    private void initialize(DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder builder) {
        this.providesApplicationProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(ApplicationModule_ProvidesApplicationFactory.create(builder.applicationModule));
    }

    public void inject(IApplication application) {
        MembersInjectors.noOp().injectMembers(application);
    }

    public IApplication getApplication() {
        return (IApplication)this.providesApplicationProvider.get();
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private ApplicationModule applicationModule;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public ApplicationComponent build() {
            if(this.applicationModule == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ApplicationModule.class.getCanonicalName() + " must be set");
            } else {
                return new DaggerApplicationComponent(this);
            }
        }

        public DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder applicationModule(ApplicationModule applicationModule) {
            this.applicationModule = (ApplicationModule)Preconditions.checkNotNull(applicationModule);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to build your project and look at generated by Dagger code. Does `app` is really injected? Are `DaggerApplicationComponent` and `DaggerRouterComponent` generated correctly? Does `ApplicationComponent` really provides `app` from `ApplicationModule`?

Comment: I did build the project so DaggerApplicationComponent should be correctly built. I'm adding the generated code to the post in case it helpt.

Comment: Should `RouterComponent` be a subcomponent of `ApplicationComponent`? I think you may only have one `@Singleton` component.
Another thing that isn't clear to me, it seems that you're passing into the `ApplicationComponent`'s init method the `Application` only to inject the same instance into itself. Is this only for the sake of testing that everything is wired up?

Comment: Yes, that application part was only to test the inject method. I was more interested in the router for example... but the process is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inject method

```
void inject(IApplication application);
```

needs to change to

```
void inject(Application application);
```

Note the change from IApplication to just Application. You can't use interfaces for inject methods, you need to use a class.

Comment: Yeah I realized this was the issue. I commented it in the previous post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, Dagger 2 component creation is done in a class extending one of Android's Application classes. This is primarily done to ensure that these components (and the dependencies they house) are only instantiated once. (see Dagger docs for more details: https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide)

While I haven't seen anything that says you can't wire it up differently, I haven't found an example of it, either. I'm wondering if trying to wire the components on-the-fly with the Initializer.init() calls you're making is somehow bypassing Dagger's ability to setup Components for injection correctly. Would it be possible to refactor the instantiation of the Component classes into an Application implementation instead?

The code above looks like it should work (outside of getting a new DaggerApplicationComponent instance with every init() call instead of a Singleton), I can't really explain why it doesn't.

Comment: The thing is that I'd like to init the routher there, with all the rest of modules but I need to use it there to go to another page. That's why I did it like this. Everywhere else I'd be good with using constructor injection. To your final point, initDagger should only be called once from the create() which is the entry point and never again. I don't get why I would be instantiating various DaggerApplicationComponents

Comment: Side note, this is LibGDX and Android .onCreate calls the Application .create.

Comment: The issue is that i was using interfaces. For example IRouter should return the new Router() from the module but it didn't. Apparently dagger doesn't assign that right. I switch to classes instead of interfaces and it worked. Is there any way to use instances? I like doing that just in case I change the implementation down the line I can just change the instantiation in the module but everywhere else it's fine because it expects a IRouter.